# How to test for return result from callback in RTL?

Tags: reactjs, react-testing-library

I expect `callback` to return either `true` or `false`. I know how to test for function being called, but how to test if that function returned specific value? How can I do that using react testing libraries?

My code:

```
it('sends back error callback', () => {
    const isError = (val) => val;
    render(<Component callback={isError}/>);
    const input = screen.getAllByRole('textbox')[0];
    fireEvent.change(input, {target: {value: '100.98'}});
    expect(isError).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
  })
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you utilize a `Mock` (`jest.fn()`), you can simply use [`toHaveBeenCalledWith`](https://jestjs.io/docs/expect#tohavebeencalledwitharg1-arg2-).

So in your case:

```js
it("sends back error callback", () => {
  const isError = jest.fn();
  render(<Component callback={isError} />);
  const input = screen.getAllByRole("textbox")[0];
  fireEvent.change(input, { target: { value: "100.98" } });
  expect(isError).toHaveBeenCalledWith(false);
});
```

Or use this alternative, especially if you have issue with the asynchronous nature of the code:

```js
it("sends back error callback", (done) => {
  const isError = (val) => {
    expect(val).toBe(false);
    done();
  };

  render(<Component callback={isError} />);
  const input = screen.getAllByRole("textbox")[0];
  fireEvent.change(input, { target: { value: "100.98" } });
});
```

Read more about async code: https://jestjs.io/docs/asynchronous.

If you have any questions to my answer/or the answer is not working, please get back to me in the comments .

Comment: Looking into first option, for some kind of strange reason it always passes, regardless if I put `expect(isError).toHaveBeenCalledWith(false)` or `expect(isError).toHaveBeenCalledWith(true)`

Comment: I tried second option, strangely it failed saying that it returns `true`. 
`Expected: false
  Received: true`
I decided to test it and changed line to be `expect(val).toBe(true)`, to my surprise test failed again, but this time with 
`Expected: true
  Received: false`

Comment: 1. This could be because your function is called with both, there is also `toHaveBeenLastCalledWith`. You can also try to log `console.log(isError.mock.calls)` inside the callback to see what calls were made. 2. I suspect this is a problem with your component. Maybe log val (`console.log(val)` inside the callback), and check if the value is what you expect. Feel free to get back to me again 